# Get the object with the max value of a field [Mongoid]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

is there anyway to return the object and not the value from Method:

```
Mongoid::Contexts::Enumerable#max
```

[Link to the rdoc](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Contexts/Enumerable%3amax)

An easy example is if you have collection of Users and they all have field :age => can i get the users that are oldest with max or should i use something else

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
one_of_oldest_users = User.desc(:age).limit(1).first
```

That'll get you a one of users with the greatest age (in case there are several). If you want to get them all, the easiest way is to use a two-pass.

```
max_age = User.max(:age)
oldest_users = User.where(age: max_age)

# or, if you like one-liners
oldest_users = User.where(age: User.max(:age))
```

To make these queries efficient, you'll need an index on `:age`, of course.

Comment: That fails if the max age is, say, 23 and there are five that have that age.

Comment: So the only way is to sort the whole collection >?

Comment: @muistooshort: well, the question title says "**the** object". This kinda implies there's only one :)